# AM/PM Distinction when formatting datetime field from sqlite into datetime field in R

Tags: r, sqlite

I have pulled data from a sqlite table into R.  One of the columns is a string, which was a datatime in sqlite.  It is in the following format:

```
                  time_json         number
1    2013-07-08 01:06:02 AM              6
2    2013-07-08 01:08:01 AM              6
3    2013-07-08 01:12:01 AM              6
4    2013-07-08 01:14:01 AM              6
5    2013-07-08 01:16:01 AM              6
```

I need to format the time_json field into a proper date time in R, and account for the AM/PM distinction.  Nothing I've tried works.

Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, using the formats listed in `?strptime`:

```
test <- c("2013-07-08 01:06:02 AM", "2013-07-08 01:06:02 PM")

as.POSIXct(
  test,
  format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"
)
```

Result:

```
[1] "2013-07-08 01:06:02 EST" "2013-07-08 13:06:02 EST"
```